# Why is `console.table` skipping the last property?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a very simple object, but the table is just never printed fully in Chrome devtools:

```js
console.table({
  "ClassMethod#set": {
    "checked": 0,
    "unchecked": 0
  },
  "ClassMethod#get": {
    "checked": 0,
    "unchecked": 0
  },
  "ClassMethod#constructor": {
    "checked": 0,
    "unchecked": 0
  },
  "ClassMethod#method": {
    "checked": 0,
    "unchecked": 0
  },
});
```

The output is:

[image: chrome devtools]

Why does it only print three rows, when given four?

It is not a "three-limit", I can just print more, but it always lacks the last one:

[image]

Comment: Replicated in Chrome for Windows Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Looks like a new bug. Can reproduce on chrome 103.0.5060.134, cannot on 96.0.4664.110

Comment: Can confirm it is a bug Chrome 103.0.5060.134 solved that issue.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1344504&q=console.table&can=1

Comment: @Palladium02 I've updated to Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and it still appears to be an issue!

Comment: @phuzi Interesting, for me the update resolved the issue.

Comment: The issue is closed as "wontFix", but the related comment states "This has been fixed and the fix will roll out soon into Stable channel.", meaning a fix will likely roll out within the next few days. It mentions it doesn't exist anymore in 104, so soon™

Comment: May be we'll have to wait until version 104 or 105!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome it appears to be buggy, always showing one line less than specified (also with only one row).

---

You can track the open issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1344504&q=console.table&can=1) on bugs.chromium.org

*Little spoiler from a comment in the issue*

> As the issue is no longer reproducible/fixed on chrome beta channel #104.0.5112.48 which will be stable tentatively in next few weeks.

*Written  Mon, Jul 18, 2022*

Comment: That doesn't make sense, if you give it 8 rows, it only prints 7. It seems to be a one-off issue.

Comment: Weird, this behaviour doesn't appear to be documented anywhere and all the examples I can find have exactly 3 items!

Comment: If i try to print 5 rows, i get always 3 in chrome... In firefox is different

Comment: @Doc Added screenshot how Chrome easily prints more than three rows, but always one less than given.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Chrome/Chromium, try logging 8 items and I can only see 7!

Comment: You're right, my bad, i was using the same index in the other rows. It looks like a Chrome devtools bug...

Comment: @Doc If you copy in the link to the open issue that ASDFGerte posted, I will mark your answer as solution

Comment: I'm opening an issue, i will post the link in the answer as soon as i finish :)

Comment: @Doc stop bothering, it is reported already: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1344504&q=console.table&can=1

Comment: Oh, thanks, not found when searching!  Ps. Sorry but I don't understand what you mean in your last comment, could you please clarify?

Comment: @Doc You can edit your answer that its definitely a bug and link to the issue, then I just accept it as solution

Comment: PS: [there are more issues for the same problem already](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1339628&q=console.table&can=1), i only picked the first, as the specific one isn't all too relevant, just that it's known, fixed in beta, and will roll out soon.